# Highlight the UIButtons created Dynamically?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview, uibutton, ios-simulator

In my application I have created 20 buttons with in a scroll view, now problem is that I was not able to highlight the selected button.

My intention is to show the pressed button with a different look than normal. When another button is pressed the previous one should become normal:

```
UIButton *Abutton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
    [Abutton setTag:i-1];
    Abutton.frame = CGRectMake(30.0, 0+j, 40.0, 40.0);
    [Abutton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    Abutton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [Abutton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
    UIImage *buttonImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
    UIImage *strechableButtonImageNormal = [buttonImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
    [Abutton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIImage *buttonImagePressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
    UIImage *strechableButtonImagePressed = [buttonImagePressed stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
    [Abutton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImagePressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [Abutton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonpressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [scrollview addSubview:Abutton];
```

Finally I created the method for Abutton pressed as below:

```
-(IBAction)buttonpressed:(id)sender{
         Abutton.highlighted=YES;
         //.....
         //.....
}
```

If  do it like this then only the last button created dynamically gets highlighted.  That's not exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1:
Create an `NSSet` with references to all the buttons. In your `buttonPressed` method, call `makeObjectsPerformSelector` on the NSSet's buttons, setting them to the unhighlighted state.

Solution 2:
Use a UISegmentedControl. That seems like what you *should* be doing in this case anyway.

Comment: Thanks Ben, is there a better example of using NSSet?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should replace your current code for the button pressed:

```
    -(IBAction)buttonpressed:(id)sender{
UIButton *b = (UIButton *)sender;
             b.highlighted = YES;
             //.....
             //.....
    }
```

In your example you are specifically highlighting "*AButton*". This code highlights the button being pressed.